# Galaxy Tab 10.1 wifi stuck in 'Obtaining IP Address' mode

Tags: connection-issues, wifi-hotspot

Using 'Virtual Router Plus' to set up a wifi hotspot on my desktop. I can manually connect with my tablet devices a first time, but after a couple hours it times out, disconnects.

I am unable to connect a 2nd time, my Galaxy Tab is stuck in 'Obtaining IP Address' mode. Is their a way to force an Android device to 'remember' and automatically reconnect to a previous hotspot?

Answer (score 2):

"Obtaining IP Address" message means that your device has automatically reconnected to the AP.  Most likely than not the problem is on the PC side.

Answer (score 1):

after much frustration with this problem I have found a solution

1. turn off wifi on your Tablet
2. turn off your tablet
3. turn your tablet back on
4. turn on wifi

your tablet should now connect :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution for this. When I was stuck on obtaining IP address
I was using static IP using Google DNS `8.8.8.8`

Today I was trying to install Android on my PC (VMWare)and I found something in there 
and tried the same trick on my tablet and voila it worked. 
So I don't know who solved this trick but I want to share my solution here.
Which is 
`/etc/init.sh` or `init.goldfish.sh`

Edit this file using any text editor using root permissions.

add these lines

- `netcfg eth0 up` (activates the network interface)
- `netcfg eth0 dhcp` (network interface gets an IP address from DHCP)
- `setprop net.dns1 8.8.8.8` (Set the Google DNS Server)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the details for us non-nerdy guys with a Belkin Router that usually has an IP of `192.168.2.1`; others differ like `192.168.1.2`, etc.

1. Settings
2. Wi-Fi
3. Hold down desired Wi-Fi network
4. In Advanced settings, put check mark into box
5. Change IP from DHCP to STATIC
6. Scroll down and set for IP: `192.168.2.55` or `56 57 58 59`, etc.
7. Scroll down and set for gateway: `192.168.2.1`
8. Scroll down and set for prefetch: `11` (usually `24`)
9. Scroll down and set for DNS 1: `208.67.222.222`
10. Scroll down and set for DNS 2. `208.67.220.220`
11. Click save

Answer (score -2):

- go to Wi-fi settings
- first forget the network
- in "Advanced" settings choose "Static IP"
- enter following

`IP adress= (IPv4 address, ten digit number, when entering put different last digit)
Gateway= (IPv4 default gateway)
Netmask= 255.255.255.0
DNS 1= 208.67.222.222
DNS 2= 208.67.220.220`

use a computer connected to the network/router to find IPv4 address/gateway

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipCQ8SLO7lY

Comment: And who controls that DNS?

Comment: IPv4 addresses are not always ten digits, nor is the subnet always /24

Comment: @AlE. OpenDNS.com